# Outputing items from a list if not divisible by 2

Tags: java, list, indexing, output

I have a code that creates and fill an array then converts it to a list.

```
    // I made a scanner and an integer "input".
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int input = in.nextInt();
    // I make input into an array
    int[] ints = new int[input];

    // I fill the array
    for(int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++){
        ints[i] = i + 1;
    }

    // transform it into a list
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int index = 0; index < ints.length; index++)
    {
        intList.add(ints[index]);
    }
```

Now i want to output `System.out.println();` every items whose index is not devisible by 2 (items with indexes: `1` `3` `5`and so on).

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: I don't know to pick out values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not divisible by 2 means `num % 2 != 0`, so you can do:

```
if(i % 2 != 0) {
    System.out.println(whatever);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you only have to add to the `intList` if the index is not divisible by 2.

```
for(int index = 0; index < ints.length; index++)
{
    if(index % 2 != 0)
       intList.add(ints[index]);
}
```

Then you can simply print the `intList` which will only have indexes such as: `1, 3, 5, ...`

```
for(int i = 0; i < intList.size(); i++)
    System.out.println(intList.get(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you need is an `if` statement use with modulo operator.

For example like this:

> if( index % 2 == 1 ) System.out.println( ints[ index ] );

Comment: but I need to print out all values EXCEPT for the ones that have an index devisible by 2

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String []args){
   ArrayList<Integer> s = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   s.add(1);
   s.add(2);
   s.add(3);
   s.add(4);
   s.add(5);

   for(Integer sx:s){
   if(sx%2!=0){
       System.out.println(sx);
}
   }

 }
```